# Disable ability to pull a tab off of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, browser-tabs

I'm so sick of mistakenly pulling my Chrome tabs out of the tab list when i click on it, and having it open in a new window.  I'm always pulling them off, then having to drop them back.

Does anyone know of a way to disable this 'feature' of Chrome?

Comment: +1 This wrecks my head but I can't find a solution. It seems to be part of Google's strategy to turn Chrome more application driven.

Comment: Would be nice if you had to hold a modifier and then click and drag (or could configure it as such)

Comment: Just looked at it - IE 9 has some options for the tab handling, but Chrome has nothing. Saying that all current browsers seem to have the option by default and non-disablable (is there such a word?)

Comment: There is `Enable Tab Browser Dragging` option in `chrome://flags/`, the problem is that it doesn't do anything; Tab Dragging is enabled by default and can't be disabled.

Comment: I love this feature personally

Comment: "Enable Tab Browser Dragging" seems to be long gone from chrome://flags

Comment: In Chrome flags there is **enable-fullscreen-in-tab-detaching**  (chrome://flags/#enable-fullscreen-in-tab-detaching) for Mac only,  but it does not seem to work.

Comment: This is one of those odd things that I read and think **"HOW on earth do so many people have that issue!?"**

Comment: Nine years later, and no solution.  The mentioned tags above no longer exist.  This is infuriating when you accidentally drag a tab off the bar and disrupt your entire workflow.

Comment: It simply sucks!

Comment: i only noticed this happening to me as of 3/4 weeks ago...it's driving me BONKERS. I barely click on a tab and it instantly transports half a dimension away in a new window

Comment: I can't attach tabs anymore. So detaching them while trying to reorder tabs leads to fustration. Bug also shows with a fresh profile. Just switched back from Firefox because the direction Mozilla is heading to. Currently I'm unable to decide which one of the two big browsers sucks less. Using Arch Linux.

Comment: 13 years later and still no solution. wow google.

Answer (score 4):

The only time I accidentally peel off a tab is when I am trying to reorder tabs in a window with multiple tabs open. Yes, it is annoying and there should be a way to turn that off.

A solution to this: use keyboard shortcuts rather than drag and drop to move tabs. For example:

Move tab left: Ctrl Shift Page Up

Move tab right: Ctrl Shift Page Down

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the thing you are describing is NOT a feature, but a bug. It is happening more-often in the last few weeks. Clicking on a tab (not dragging it out), will shoot the tab out of the tabbed-window as a "new window". Disabling the "drag-drop" feature would not work. Since this actually has nothing to do with dragging tabs out of the window.

The misconception is that you THINK it is related, because it happens when you try to drag a tab around. However, it jumps out of the window instead. It is just the action of clicking that triggers the bug. (It's also not a "double-click misfire", as double-clicking on a tab does nothing. It is also not a "move tab to new window", because the new window is always in position -32,-32 for top and left. A position you can't even place an actual tab or window.)

Fortunately, it is a little rare to happen. I can go hours without it happening, then it will start glitching and happen several times in an hour, as I flip through tabs. (Seems to also be related to, or limited to happening only after focus of the mouse has been outside the browser window for a while. When you return and click a tab, that is when it jumps out of the window and opens as a new window. Something you would never see in "full-screen", by the way... It would just jump back into the same window, but the order might shift to slot-0 or slot-{last}. I am sure it's related to the annoying "ability" that some bad pages have when they push a tab out of the window and hide it in the bottom-right corner of the screen. However, this natively jumps to the "min-top/left" position instead. I have confirmed that it is not page-related, because it happens on blank pages and google's own search page too.) But it is surely a bug, as that operation was NEVER intended, by any user. Nor is it even a documented "feature" or "ability". With the exception of "drag and drop", or "open tab in a new window", which this has nothing, directly, to do with.

Answer (score 1):

I looked around a bit and it seems the option to disable this does not exist. So this is not exactly the answer to disable this feature, but you can:-

```
-Use ctrl + tab and to move forward through the tabs of chrome 
-Use ctrl + shift + tab to move back through the tabs of chrome 
-Use ctrl + <tab no:> (eg : ctrl + 5 for the 5th tab) to jump to a tab in chrome
```

If you do get a hang of these shorcut keys (I know I did) you will never have the problem of pulling chrome tabs out of the tabs list.

```
-Oh and using ctrl + w closes a tab
-using ctrl + t opens a new tab and
-the F6 function key takes you to the omnibox. (address bar)
```

Comment: The reason we pull tabs is to have a referential page side by side or on another monitor. While FF reopens all 'windows' upon crash or close, Chrome grandly only opens the last window closed. So if we accidentally close the window with all our pinned tabs, we end up with a clean (unwanted) slate when we reopen Chrome, whether it has crashed or not and have to re-do all our pinned tabs again.

Comment: just wanted to add: ctrl + pgup  previous tab; ctrl + pgdn next tab

Comment: @killjoy Settings → History → Recently Closed will list recently-closed tabs (or entire groups of tabs) in the event you accidentally close an entire window full of tabs.

Comment: @Matt If I wanted to painfully open each tab I would just do it with the 1-shot Ctrl+H; But Chrome seems to have fixed this bug and it now opens all sessions...so joy! Also it now very politely even asks 'Would you like to open your last session' ? Of course the joy will be short-lived; when the Gods@Google decide to pull the plug on that feature as they do to every other nice-to-have-feature in the past decades

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me as well quite some time. Maybe give the *Windows To Tabs* plugin a shot, it gives you the ability to merge all open chrome windows as tabs into one window. It does not prevent you from pulling tabs out, but at least lets you reverse the action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a way to do exactly what you want, but I don't know it. Here is a possible work around.

upper right under the X click ⫶
towards the end of the list click "settings"
scroll down to the bottom and choose "Open a specific page or set of pages"
paste all the url's you want to automatically load when you open chrome

In addition you can adjust your mouse and or touchpad settings, like sensitivity and how fast the mouse moves in response to your touch.  It sounds like your struggling with your cursor.  tap windows key,  type mouse or touchpad and that will pull up your settings for that.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this thread is quite old, but the problem still exists and the browser manufacturers still haven't provided any way to disable this behavior. I looked around for the "Windows to Tabs" extension and couldn't find it anywhere, but I did find a "Merge Windows" extension in the Chrome Store that does exactly the same thing in Chrome, Brave, and Microsoft Edge, all with a single click and no mouse dragging required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've used well the "pin tab" function for tabs that I want "in place".

Also, in your place, I'll **try** to do my mouse a little less sensitive/responsive for the press/click, or the reaction time before click to the move with button pressed, or touch-pad for taps.

Just some ideas, out of Chrome, which, honestly, I don't think will soon (if ever) change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

go to settings then Bluetooth and devices then go to touchpad, then go to taps, then turn off tap twice and drag to multiselect. Surprisingly it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there doesn't seem to be a way to disable the pulloff behavior, so I use a workaround. In one of the existing answers, @Thomas mentioned keyboard shortcuts for reordering tabs. As for me, I generally find myself accidentally pulling off a tab when I'm trying to move the whole Chrome window. This happens a lot because there are only a few pixels' worth of room between the top of the tab row and the top of the window. I can avoid the problem by using keyboard shortcuts to move the window. Here's how to do it on Windows 10:

- make sure the Chrome window has the focus
- press Alt-Space
- release the keys
- type "m" for "Move"
- use the arrow keys to move the window
- press Enter once you have the window in the desired place

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution.
Switch to firefox. Has much better behavior, it does not split the tab into another window until you let go of the button. So you never accidentally detach the tab while trying to just move it (which happens ALL the time on chrome.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).