# How to disable tabs drag & drop in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, drag-and-drop, browser-tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Disable ability to pull a tab off of Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/300840/disable-ability-to-pull-a-tab-off-of-chrome)

I want to fully disable tabs drag & drop in Google Chrome. I still want to be able to slide my tabs and arrange them, but I don't want to be able to drag them out of the tabs panel (thus opening them a new separate window).

### **All Tabs:**

When I try to slide my tabs and arrange them, I'm not able to drag them outside of my current window *by dragging them upwards*, (if the window is maximized), but I'm still able to do that *by dragging them downwards*:

[image: Tab Drag & Drop in Google Chrome]

I want to slide my tabs and arrange them freely, without making sure I'm pushing them up   while sliding them, so I won't drag them out and open them in a new separate window by mistake.

### **Newly opened tabs:**

I'm not sure if it's a bug or not - but when I open a new tab and try to slide it to the left or to the right just after opening it, it will often drag the tab outside of the current (maximized) window and open it in a new separate window, as soon as I click on it (even if I click on on it and only move it a little bit up or down).

It's much more sensitive and it happens also when dragging the tab upwards - which is unusual (in a maximized window). It happens only when sliding a newly opened tab.